# Can the ActiveMQ Web Console Be Customized?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'd like to customize the ActiveMQ web console to display a column for a custom header. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible indeed, the web console files are located in `%AMQROOT%/webapps/admin` and it should be sufficient for applying small changes.

If you are looking for a more flexible way, I'd suggest you move over to hawtio (http://hawt.io/) and create your own fork of the `activemq plugin` (https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/activemq).